# Replacing and Patching classes in Android projects

Tags: java, android, jar

For a Android project, I need to use an existing library packaged as a JAR.

This JAR however contains a class which performs Base64 encoding using javax.xml.DatatypeConverter.

To use the library on Android, I need to remove this class from the JAR, and replace it with a class which uses the Android Base64 implementation.

One option is to delete the incompatible class from JAR directly, and provide the Android replacement in my Android Studio project. This works as expected.

Question: are there better ways to 'replace' (hide) the original class, which do not require manipulation of the JAR?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but how about including a file named javax.xml.DatatypeConverter and implementing the interface to call the version you want?  We use similar tricks when accessing hidden APIs.

Comment: In my tests, the DEX compiler complains about duplicate classes and exits with an error

Comment: Oh, so the converter class is in that jar? Then you're stick with editing the jar- although I'm not sure why you feel the need top replace it then. Base64 should be identical through either